# Bash loop between 2 date doesn't stop at the end of a month

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, unix-timestamp

I have a bash script with 2 dates in parameters. I want to loop between this 2 dates by using the day. So I wrote this code :

```
START_DATE=$1
END_DATE=$2

for ((date=$START_DATE; date != "$END_DATE + 1"; ));do
           echo $END_DATE
           date="$(date --date="$date + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
done
```

My date is on this format : 20150226 for example

So my script is running well until END_DATE is a this end of the month (e.g 20150228, 20141231 20150131 ...)

Do you have any advice to face this bug ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use numeric math on non-numeric (date stamp) values. Or if you want to do that use values in seconds.

Comment: So what should i use ?

Comment: Convert the timestamps to seconds from epoch (those are numerically usable) or find some other way to detect the end of your range loop.

Comment: Just a note: if `END_DATE` is `20150228`, then `ENDDATE+1` is `20150229`.  Because it's not a leap year, `date` will never equal that, and you'll get an infinite loop.   You could do 'ENDDATE_PLUS_ONE=$(date --date="$END_DATE + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')', and compare against that.

Comment: Etan -- there are a few sharp sticks with seconds -- namely due to daylight savings time.   If you add 24 hours on the spring day, you might come up short of $END_DATE.   You could likely get around this by comparing (using less than) against END_DATE plus say twelve hours, but that seems non-intuative.

Comment: There are so many little edge cases with date calculations, it's ridiculous. Our application barfed in the fall for a Brazilian user because Brazil chooses to do it's DST transition at midnight. We had $today + 1 day return an "invalid time" error because there's no 00:00:00 on that day in the Brazil time zone. Ugh

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems here :

`"$END_DATE + 1"` was evaluated to a string `"20150228 + 1"`.

And `20150228 + 1 != 20150301`

```
START_DATE=$1
END_DATE=$2
previous=$(( $1 - 1 ))

for (( date=$START_DATE; previous == date - 1; ));do
    echo $date
    previous=$date
    date="$(date --date="$date + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
done
```

Comment: It doesn't run , I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
date=${1:-20150226}
end_date=${2:-20150310}

while [[ $date < $end_date ]]
do
    echo $date not reached $end_date
    date=$(gdate --date="$date + 1 days" +'%Y%m%d')
done
```

prints

```
20150226 not reached 20150310
20150227 not reached 20150310
20150228 not reached 20150310
20150301 not reached 20150310
20150302 not reached 20150310
20150303 not reached 20150310
20150304 not reached 20150310
20150305 not reached 20150310
20150306 not reached 20150310
20150307 not reached 20150310
20150308 not reached 20150310
20150309 not reached 20150310
```